# Extra link icon next to "Edit CV"

Tags: bug, status-completed

Having two icons here looks unintentional:

[image]

Can we delete this?

[image]

The `::before` adds the icon; the extra `span` adds another.

Comment: Derp. Fixing...

Answer (score 2):

All better.

[image]